# ¿Qué quiere decir esto en javascript (store) => (next) => (action) => { } ?

Tags: javascript, babel

En unos tutoriales de redux me tope con la siguiente forma de declarar una función que va actuar de middleware, la pregunta es que es lo que esta pasando en esta parte de la función: **(store) => (next) => (action) =>**

```
const logger = (store) => (next) => (action) => {
    // logger body...
    next(action)
}
```

osea toma store de input y luego qué pasa ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La función que muestras [es la forma ES6](http://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=latest%2Creact%2Cstage-2&experimental=false&loose=false&spec=false&code=const%20logger%20%3D%20(store)%20%3D%3E%20(next)%20%3D%3E%20(action)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20logger%20body...%0A%20%20%20%20next(action)%0A%7D&playground=true) de escribir la siguiente función:

```
var logger = function logger(store) {
    return function (next) {
        return function (action) {
            // logger body...
            next(action);
        };
    };
};
```

Ésta es la estructura básica de un middleware para redux, que luego pasarás como parámetro en `applyMiddleware(logger)`, donde internamente espera recibir esa estructura de 3 funciones anidadas.
El por qué son tres funciones, la gran mayoría de las veces no te debería preocupar y simplemente escribir tu código dentro de la última función anidada, pero si igual quedas con la duda, lo que hace en cada caso, sería algo como esto:

```
var logger = function logger(store) {
    // De aquí podrías acceder a store.dispatch() y store.getState()
    return function (next) {
        // Esto se ejecuta en createStore()
        return function (action) {
            // Esto se ejecutaría en cada dispatch() invocado, que en este caso
            // sería la función que nombraste como next()
        };
    };
};
```

[Aquí hay algunos ejemplos](http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/Middleware.html) donde necesites definir código para más de una de estas funciones.

Answer (score 1):

**Argumentos**

`Middlewares`( Argumentos ): Funciones que cumplen con el `Redux API` de middleware . Cada middleware recibe `Store's` `dispatch` y `getState` funciones como argumentos con nombre, y devuelve una función. Esa función se le dará el `next` método de envío de middleware, y se espera que regrese una función de action llamada `next(action)` con un argumento potencialmente diferente, o en un momento diferente, o tal vez no llamar a él en absoluto. El último middleware en la cadena recibirá de la tienda real `dispatch` método que el `next` parámetro, poniendo así fin a la cadena. Así, la firma es el middleware `({ getState, dispatch }) => next => action`.

**Devoluciones** (Returns)

(Función) potenciador Una tienda que se aplica el middleware dado. La firma tienda potenciador es `createStore => createStore` sino la forma más fácil de aplicar que es para pasarlo a `createStore()` como el último `enhancer` argumento.

[Ejemplo ver aqui](http://redux.js.org/docs/api/applyMiddleware.html)

Comment: Pero esto es solo una traducción de google de una parte del artículo que enlazaste. ¿podrías explicar de que forma esto se relaciona con lo preguntado?